# GraphQL bulk resolve / Prevent complex type request overhead

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

Assume we have a model `Book` which contains another model `Author`.
Now lets send a query like:

```
query Book {
    newestBooks(count: 200) {
        id
        title
        author {
            name
        }
    }
}
```

In my `BookResolver` I provide a method `getAuthor()` which is called once for each `Book`.
If the `getAuthor()` method loads the author from another service over the network or from the database a lot of overhead will occur for a large number of `Books`.

Is there a way in GraphQL to do some kind of a bulk request for populating the author field of the `n` `Book` instances?

I am evaluationg GraphQL with Java and Spring Boot, but I guess this topic is only concept and not environment related...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the DataLoader [concept](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader). DataLoader ported to Java is available [here](https://github.com/graphql-java/java-dataloader).

Comment: Cool, seems to be the solution I've been looking for!